# Plot point with symbolic coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to plot the point (x1,C(x1)) with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$C$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$},
        xmin={[normalized]0},
        xmax={[normalized]5},
        xtickmax={[normalized]4},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$C(x_1)$, $C(x_2)$, $C(x_3)$,          $C(x_4)$},
        ymin={[normalized]0},
        ymax={[normalized]5},
        ytickmax={[normalized]4},
        ytick distance=1]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,$C(x_1)$)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it does not work because the statement:

```
\addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,$C(x_1)$)};
```

is wrong. How can I fix the error?

Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `$C(x_1' has not been def

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps not immediately obvious from John's answer, but whenever you have a parenthesis in one of the components, you need to put that component in braces. I.e. `({x}, {y})`, to hide the closing parenthesis from the parser. You can see from your error that it stops reading the coordinate then it meets the last paren in `C(x_1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the parser was looking for a `)` and grabbed the wrong one.  Also, spaces count in symbolic coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$C$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$},
        xmin={0},
        xmax={$x_4$},
        xtickmax={$x_3$},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$C(x_1)$,$C(x_2)$,$C(x_3)$,$C(x_4)$},
        ymin={0},
        ymax={$C(x_4)$},
        ytickmax={$C(x_3)$},
        ytick distance=1]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,0)};
        \addplot [color=green,mark=*] coordinates {(0,{$C(x_1)$})};
        \addplot [color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,{$C(x_1)$})};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```